# Log deleted messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi im Hoping someone can help me with  #.Deleted Message. I'm trying to get it to log any deleted messages in a Channel called `logs`. I have defined the channel at the top of the script using channel I.D. Bot logs is the channel I.D

```
bot_logs = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted", color=0xf40000)
    embed.add_field(name="Before", value=message.content + ": was Deleted!", inline=False)
    await channel.send(discord.Object(id=bot_logs), embed=embed)
```

At the moment i keep getting **Undefined variable 'channel'**

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a message to a specific channel by getting the `GuildChannel` object via [`Guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)

```
channel = message.guild.get_channel(bot_logs)  # bot_logs must be an integer id
if channel is None:
    print("Channel not found")
else:
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks, when i do that i then get ```Undefined variable 'channel' ``` The channel i want to send them to is Logs. ```Discord.object(id=bot_logs)``` is the channel.

Comment: Oh, if you're trying to send it to a specific channel you have an id for, use `Guild.get_channel`.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate the help, this works perfect